# Unable to open database file

Tags: python, database, django, sqlite

I'm trying to install a sqlite3 database for my Django setup on my computer but can't seems to get this working. I have below.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\cms\cms.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`ENGINE` needs to be: `django.db.backends.sqlite3`

Also, do not use the global site-packages directory for your databases. Did you go through the tutorial? Your database file should be in the same directory where you created your applications (the same directory, or any subdirectory under the same directory where your `settings.py` file is).

EDIT:

What you need to do, once your have installed django correctly:

1. Open the command prompt
2. From ***any other directory***, like say `C:\Projects` (first, `cd` into that directory).
3. Then, type `django_admin.exe startproject cms`, so your command should be `C:\Projects\>django_admin.exe startproject cms`
4. Now you have a directory `cms`, change into it `cd cms`
5. Next, edit `settings.py` (so in `C:\Projects\cms>`)

Change the databases dictionary to this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'cms.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
}
```

Now run `python manage.py syncdb` from `C:\Projects\cms` directory

Comment: Yep, my database is in the "cms" directory which is in the site package directory.  I did the same thing before and there was no problem.  I tried "django.db.backends.sqlite3" but it still did not work :(

Comment: You didn't understand what burhan said. You should **not** put your own code into the site-packages directory, and even less in the bin subdirectory of that. Put it in a separate folder, *not* under site-packages.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced that. Solved it by using "cms.sqlite" in the path, and not "cms.db". Try and see if it works?